# get number of weeks passing month and year php

Tags: php, date

i know that have alot of question like this one, but i dont know if i'm blind or what, but i cant find a answer that qualify to my question, so here it go.

i have 2 combobox - `month` and `year`, i need a function that bring to me the week number's from the month and year that i selected.

**example:**

i select the date 02/2012 (m/yyyy), and the combo will bring the weeks that belongs to the month that i select. ( **weeks from the year** ).

weeks:

`5, 6, 7, 8, 9`

---

my main objective is to pass to another function the week number to get the day's that this week have, like the returns of this function:

```
$week_number = 40;
$year        = 2012;

if($week_number < 10){
   $week_number = "0".$week_number;
}

for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++)
{
    echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($year."W".$week_number.$day))."<br/>";
}
```

dont know if i make my self clear,but, any question by my guest.

Thanks.

---

resume:

52 weeks in a year

if i choose the month 2, the function should return `5, 6, 7, 8, 9`.

Comment: Just to clarify...Shouldn't the weeks for February 2012 be { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }?

Comment: damn, will try again: passing the month and the year, how can i get the week number's from this month ?

Comment: @Hardryv the week number's that i put there was just a example.

Comment: @LaurenceBurke: like Hardryv say, if i pass February 2012, i need to get this weeks.

Comment: @Hardryv: Better late than never! ISO-8601 weeks run from Monday to Sunday. Week 9 of 2012 is in March, because the year's ninth Thursday is on 1st March, so most of week 9 is in March. To be exact, three days of the week are in April while four are in March.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you should be able to work with this?

```
$month = "2";
$year = "2012";

$beg = (int) date('W', strtotime("first thursday of $year-$month"));
$end = (int) date('W', strtotime("last  thursday of $year-$month"));

print(join(', ', range($beg, $end)));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
5, 6, 7, 8
```

---

**Note**

*This code was faulty, and produced incorrect results until it was fixed on 27-Aug-2014.*

The time period that a week belongs to is determined by where most (four or more) of its days are. That is most simply determined by checking where its *Thursday* falls. So the first and last weeks of a month are the ones containing its first and last Thursdays.

Comment: something like that, but i need all days from the week, not just the begin and end.

Comment: If you can't get there from what I've given you then you have *real* problems! I've amended my answer to produce an array.

Comment: +1.  Personally, I think `(int)<string>` is more explicit and readable than `0 + <string>`, though.

Comment: @Ricardo: Changed again to deliver *exactly* what you asked for.

Comment: if i have passed $month = 12 and $year = 2014 it is not working fine
it gives $beg=49 $end=1

49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

Comment: @RahulChipad: Thanks. The same thing happens on some Januaries too. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

First, get the timestamp for the 1st day of the month/year. And based on that, get the week number of the first day.

Like this:

```
$year = "2012";
$mon = "02";

$tm = strtotime("$year-$mon-01");  # Substitue year and month 
$first_week_num = date("W", $tm); # Got the week number
```

And then do the same for the last day of the month. For that, you can simply add 1 to the month (you need to do the logic, if the month is 12 - where you need to add 1 to the year). And then subtract 86400 (number of seconds per day). This way you will get the last day of the month and not bother about finding how many days in that month.

```
if($mon == 12) 
   $year++;
else
   $mon++;
$tm = strtotime("$year-$mon-01") - 86400;
$last_week_num = date("W", $tm);
```

And all the weeks from the first week to the last week is what you need:

```
for($i=$first_week_num; $i <= $last_week_num; $i++)
  print $i;
```

Comment: Such a long-winded way to do `strtotime("last day of $year-$mon")`

Comment: @Borodin: Agreed :-) Didn't realize such expressive strings are acceptable for strtotime! Thanks!

Comment: All sorts of nice things in [Relative Date Formats](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)!